# How can I programmatically insert an image into an Excel file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, microsoft-excel

I have a folder with an Excel file and an image. Which programming language can I use to insert the image to a cell programmatically? The files are located on a Linux server running a strictly terminal version of Ubuntu. My original plan was to use Python or PowerShell to activate a Visual Basic macro I had written in the Excel file, but macros would require the workbook to be open, which is not possible in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/), which is full of great info, not just what you ask.

[Chapter 12 – Working with Excel Spreadsheets](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) should tell you what you want to know.